# What are best words to reflect properties of time and being centralized or decentralized?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm trying to reflect my research contributions in a table in an organized fashion.

Assume that 4 derivations of problem `P` are defined (and solved) as follows:

- **Centralized** solution to the **untimed** P
- **Decentralized** solution to the **untimed** P
- **Centralized** solution to the **timed** P
- **Decentralized** solution to the **timed** P

I'm gonna design a table as below:

[image]

however, I don't know what terminologies are suitable for labeling the columns. The first column determines the dependency on time, so my initial guess is `temporality`; although, I'm not sure whether it is a good word or not.

For the second column, I have no idea at all!

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe centrality

Comment: Please do not post images of text. The cannot be indexed and are inaccessible to blind or partially sighted people.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your complete research, so I am not very sure. You can try **Timing Constraint** for the first column and **Solution Scope/Scale** for the second one.

And in case you are flexible with your table structure, you can tabulate the whole thing like below :

[image]

Keys :

> Sol 1 : Centralized solution to a Timed problem.
>
> Sol 2 : Decentralized solution to a Timed problem.
>
> Sol 3 : Centralized solution to an Untimed problem.
>
> Sol 4 : Decentralized solution to an Untimed problem.

I hope this was helpful ! :)